# Azure B2C integration in ASP.NET Website crashing

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-ad-b2c

Good day.

When I click sign in, it loads up, then redirects to my initial page without going to the Azure B2C page. This behaviour is weird since I had gotten Azure B2C working and it started recently

I am using the following packages to hook up Azure AD B2C

```
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="7.0.2" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.2" NoWarn="NU1605" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web" Version="1.26.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.26.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

On Azure, I have set up the user flows and I am consuming them in a .NET MAUI application that is allowing authentication just fine. I have brushed over the debug, console, hot reload tabs but there is no error being logged.

appsettings.json

```
{
  "AzureAdB2C": {
    "Instance": "https://****.b2clogin.com/",
    "Domain": "****.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "cb6**************685",
    "ClientId": "592******d1a",
    "CallbackPath": "/home",
    "SignUpSignInPolicyId": "B2C_1_signupsignin",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout/B2C_1_susi",
    "ResetPasswordPolicyId": "bB2C_1_passwordreset",
    "EditProfilePolicyId": "B2C_1_edit_profile",
    "EnablePiiLogging": true
  },
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is pretty much impossible to tell what the problem could be if you don't give more information about how you have configured the authentication. Crashes should also result in errors in your logging, which would also be good to add here.

Comment: I am checking the logs, there's nothing. Debugged it, nothing. I'll add more information now

Comment: You can also try using a tool like Fiddler to inspect the traffic between your app and Azure AD B2C to see if there are any issues with the authentication flow.